# Database Schema of weekly schedule vb

Tags: vb6, database-schema

Here's my database..

```
**call_code**           **events**              **activity**           **users**
call_id                  event_id                activity_id            user_id
maintCall_plan           activity_id             activity_desc          username
maintCall_unplanned      day(monday, etc)        contact_person         fname
creditCalls              event_date                                     lname
newBussCalls             time(8-6)                                      mname
phoneCalls               user_id
                         call_id
```

What i wanted to do is to sort the events/activity per week of the month depending on what day it is (e.g Monday, Tuesday, etc) the time of the event is fixed from 8am-6pm. does this database design will do the trick?

Comment: What is wrong with schema, laid out in your question? (Except day, which probably means weekday and needs not to be stored in database.) Sure you could replace callcode, contact and activity with "comboboxes" (links to corresponding tables in database structure), but date-time part looks OK. Unless you start using half hours or minutes or something :)

Comment: Day means monday, tuesday, etc.
the contact and activity is not a static record. 
can you help me make a normalized database? @Arvo

Comment: Write down initial schema (tables, fields, relations - whatever you think would suit your task) - then other users can start making suggestions, asking specific questions etc.

Comment: I have a call_code table which have 5 columns (call_id,maintCall_paln, maintCall_unplanned, creditCalls, newBussCalls, phoneCalls), activity table which have 8 columns (activity_id, activity_desc, day, start_time, end_time, call_id, revenue act_date and employee_id) and employee table. I wanted to display the daily schedule of every employee @Arvo

Comment: Edit your question and present your database schema in some readable (semi-graphical) way. It is impossible to respond to plain text comment :)